# Use youtube-dl to download new videos from channel

Tags: bash, youtube, youtube-dl

I need to use youtube-dl to download new videos from a channel, but remember not to download them next time and only download videos that have not been downloaded yet. How can I do so?

Comment: who ever voted this as a general question needs to go and get a life.

Comment: I suspect that the persons that closed this question don't even know what youtube-dl is and what the question implies.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `--download-archive` option:

```
youtube-dl --download-archive ~/.mydownloads http://youtube.com/CHANNEL
```

The IDs of all downloaded videos will be recorded in the `.mydownloads` file, and these videos will not be downloaded again.